# How to loop over defined name pattern

Tags: c++, c

I have around 500 signals with the naming pattern

```
"Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._101"
"Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._102"
"Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._103"
...
"Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._490"
```

I want to loop over all of them.

I tried the following code but when i=10 then my signal name is like " Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._1010" which is false it should be 110 at the end.

```
for (i=1; i<=3;i++)
  {
    SPrint(signal, "Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._10%d", i);
```

How to loop over 490 signals of same name pattern? please help! Thank you

Comment: It's not really clear what's not working for you in the code that you have posted (apart from changing that loop to iterate 490 times instead of 3 times).

Comment: You also need to specify the language, C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: Do you have signals below `100`? If so, how should they be formatted? "`._001`" or perhaps "`._1`"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want something this:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 490 - 100; i++)
{
  SPrint(signal, "Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._%d", i + 100);
```

or maybe this:

```
for (i = 101; i <= 490; i++)
{
  SPrint(signal, "Dem_AllEventsStatusByte._%d", i);
```

Comment: yes exactly, this is exactly what i want. Thank you